# .NET Encoding.Default alternative in wxWIdgets?

Tags: c++, encoding, wxwidgets, default

I need to read files with different encodings. Unicode files are correctly read using

```
wxFileInputStream fileInputStream(dialog->GetPath());
wxTextInputStream textInputStream(fileInputStream);
```

If I need to read, say, Cyrillic (cp1251) files, I use:

```
wxFileInputStream fileInputStream(dialog->GetPath());
wxTextInputStream textInputStream(fileInputStream, " \n", wxCSConv(wxFONTENCODING_CP1251));
```

But neither of these ways works with both kinds of files. In .NET we can just use:

```
new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default)
```

So what's the alternative of Encoding.Default in wxWidgets or in C++ in general?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using `wxConvAuto(wxFONTENCODING_SYSTEM)` instead of `wxCSConv(wxFONTENCODING_SYSTEM)`. The wxConvAuto function first tries to read the file as a Unicode document, and then if it fails, it uses system's encoding to read the ANSI file. It works great!

Answer (score 1):

I believe [wxFONTENCODING_SYSTEM](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxfontencodingoverview.html) would be analogous to Encoding.Default.

Comment: @Alex, I believe that Encoding.Default only "works" because MS is playing with the data.  See the big warning message here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx.  wxWidgets is probably playing it safer, see here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_nonenglish.html#overview_nonenglish_strings